# @Transient can't get data from Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

In my project, in the repository, I have a select that displays all the data I need, including those months for which I don’t have data. To do this, in my select, I create a temporary column, which I named tneDate .

```
@Query(value = "SELECT \n" +
            "  theDate, asl.id, asl.interest_payment, asl.interest_rate, asl.principal_payment, asl.total_payment, asl.actual_delta, \n" +
            "  asl.date, asl.modified, asl.interest_payment_modified, asl.amortization_schedule_initial_id, asl.tranche_id, asl.outstanding_usd,\n" +
            "  asl.disbursement, asl.floating_index_rate, asl.upfront_fee, asl.commitment_fee, asl.other_fee, asl.withholding_tax, \n" +
            "  asl.default_fee, asl.prepayment_fee, asl.total_out_flows, asl.net_flows, asl.user_id, asl.outstanding_principal, asl.new_row\n" +
            "FROM\n" +
            "  GENERATE_SERIES\n" +
            "  (\n" +
            "    (SELECT MIN(ams.date) FROM amortization_schedules ams),\n" +
            "    (SELECT MAX(ams.date) + INTERVAL '1' MONTH FROM amortization_schedules ams),\n" +
            "    '1 MONTH'\n" +
            "  ) AS tab (theDate)\n" +
            "FULL JOIN amortization_schedules asl on to_char(theDate, 'yyyy-mm') = to_char(asl.date, 'yyyy-mm')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AmortizationSchedule> findAllByDate();
```

Now, through the getter in Entity , I want to get only this tneDate , that is, the date that I form. I don't want it to be written to the database. Therefore, I put the @Transient annotation, but as I understand it, this annotation ignores the getter of this entity and I cannot get this data, since I get NULL. In this part :

```
else {
                        BigDecimal swaprate = getRate(previousAmortiz.getDate(), previousAmortiz.getTranche().getLocalCurrency().getId());
                        childReports.add(createChild(previousAmortiz.getOutstandingPrincipal(), swaprate, previousAmortiz.getTheDate()));
```

My Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "amortization_schedules")
public class AmortizationSchedule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private Date theDate;

    @Column(name = //)
    private BigDecimal //;
```

how do i get the tneDate data?

Comment: You could try `@Column(updatable=false, insertable=false)` instead of `@Transient`.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is @javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [thedate] in table [amortization_schedules]

Comment: @Thomas I get an error if I change Transient

Comment: leave entity as it is (or remove `theData` from it entirely) but change return type of `findAllByDate` to some new class `AmortizationScheduleProjection` and use projection to populate fields `@Query("select 
new xxx.AmortizationScheduleProjection(abc,xyz) from ...")`

Comment: Transient doesn't do what you think it does - it makes the java property transient, so invisible to JPA. Nothing you do on a managed entity will have it populate or persist that property once it is marked Transient by design. In this case, you are trying to populate a java object with raw data from an SQL query - either use the data in its raw form (object[]), use a AmortizationSchedule constructor to let JPA build the results (see SQLResultSetMappings and constructor queries) or use spring projections as suggested above.